# Ensure that all other threads have completed their kth calls to critical() before a thread call critical() (k+1) time

Tags: java, multithreading

I am a newbie to Multithreading in Java and have run into the following:

**Problem:**
Threads 1 to n execute a method called *critical()*. Before this, they execute a method called *uncritical()*. They synchronizations constraint is that only one can execute *critical()* at a time, and all threads must have completed executing *uncritical()* before *critical()* can be called. You can assume *n* is stored in a variable *n* that is accessible from all threads. Design a synchronization mechanism for the threads. All threads must execute the same code. Threads may call *critical()* multiple times, and you should ensure that a thread cannot call *critical()* a *(k+1)* time until all other treads have completed their *kth* calls to *critical()*.

Here is an idea (I might be completely wrong):

```
public class CriticalMonitor{
    public static int N = 0;

    public CriticalMonitor(int )

    public void uncritical(int threadID){
        System.out.println(“Thread ” + threadID+“: Uncritical!”);
        N--;
        if(N== 0) notifyAll();
     }

    public synchronized void critical(int threadID){
       while(N!=0){
         try{
            wait();
          }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println(“Critical failed”);
          }
        }
        System.out.println(“Thread ” + threadID+“: Critical!”);

     }
 }

public static class CriticalThread extends Thread{
    private final CriticalMonitor monitor;
    private int threadId;

    public CriticalThread (CriticalMonitor m, int id){
       monitor = m;
       monitor.N++;
       threadId = id;
    }

    public void run(){
       monitor.uncritical(threadId);
       //random number of calls to critical()?
       int rand = (int)(Math.random()*5); 
       while(rand>=0){
         monitor.critical(threadId);
         rand--;
        }
     }
 }
```

The issue that I cannot wrapped my head around is how to ensure that all other treads have completed their *kth* calls to *critical()* before a thread call *critical()* *(k+1)* time.

Comment: See [`java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use CyclicBarrier

You can create a [CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) with the number of threads `n`.

- To implement call `uncritical()` before all `critical()`, you can
  just let the barrier `await` before `critical()`. When all n threads has executed `uncritical()`, they will trip the barrier together.
- To implement a thread cannot call critical() a (k+1) time until all
  other threads have completed their kth calls to critical(), I think you can adjust the loop. Even if they need not call `critical()`,
  they should call `await`. So in every round, every thread will let the barrier know they have reached the point. And after the last one arrives, all threads will get into next round together.
- And in CriticalMonitor, you do not need `wait-notify` anymore, just
  use `syncronize` keyword on `critical()` method to protect it only be executed by one thread at a time.

The code should like this.

```
public class CriticalThread extends Thread {

    private final CriticalMonitor monitor;
    private int threadId;
    private CyclicBarrier barrier;

    public CriticalThread(CriticalMonitor m, int id, CyclicBarrier barrier) {
        monitor = m;
        monitor.N++;
        threadId = id;
        this.barrier = barrier;
    }

    public void run() {
        monitor.uncritical(threadId);
        //random number of calls to critical()?
        try {
            barrier.await();
            int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 5);
            int time = 0;
            int limit = 5;
            while (time < limit) {
                if (rand > 0) {
                    monitor.critical(threadId);
                    rand--;
                }
                barrier.await();
                time++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

### Using AtomicInteger

First, you need set as `AtomicInteger` to gurantee memory-visibility. In every `critical` you need decrement N, while in the loop increment N.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class CriticalMonitor {
    public static int SOURCE_N = 0;
    public static AtomicInteger N = new AtomicInteger(SOURCE_N);
    public static ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
    public static Condition condition = lock.newCondition();


    public void uncritical(int threadID) {
        System.out.println("Thread " + threadID + ": Uncritical!");
        N.getAndDecrement();
        if (N.get() == 0) {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                condition.signalAll();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }

        }
    }

    public void critical(int threadID) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (N.get() != 0) {
                try {
                    condition.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Critical failed");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Thread " + threadID + ":Critical !");
            N.getAndDecrement();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

CriticalThread

```
while(rand >= 0){
        monitor.critical(threadId);
        rand--;
        N.getAndIncrement();
        if (N.get() == 0) {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                condition.signal();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: Smart! Any idea how to solve it without the CyclicBarrier? The problem explicitly states the following: 'You can assume n is stored in a variable n that is accessible from all threads.' and I wonder how I should use that piece of information.

Answer (score -1):

After each call to uncritical() call `yourthreadName.join()` on your threads and then call your critical() method.

Comment: Thread.join() waits for the thread to die.  How does this help solve his problem?